# How to search for items in a list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement to search github API for fetching repositories or users and display it.

I have tried the below code, but cannot able to filter by name from API.

Can someone help on this?

```js
var searchValue = document.getElementById("search").innerHTML;
function UserAction() {
        
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             alert(this.responseText);
             //Show the name based on filter
              if (searchValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)            {
             //display the list of users below
           }
         }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q="+searchValue, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send("Your JSON Data Here");
}
```

```html
Search Repo..<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for names.." onkeyup="UserAction()" />
```

I'm expecting an output like below in pure javascript, strictly no jquery or any other frameworks.

[image]

Can someone help on this?

Comment: Consider sending requests less frequently, possibly only on `enter`. I got a `"message": "API rate limit exceeded for <my IP>` after only a few characters

Comment: As per github, limit is 10 per minute, if you are authenticated it is 50 per minute. Is it possible to debounce to prevent multiple requests being fired?  because I need to have this when searching in the input field instead of button click

Comment: Sure, you might send a request only after the input field has been unchanged for 1 second, or something like that

Comment: Can you help on this? How can I handle such request?

Comment: @UI_Dev you can make a variable to hold the return value of `setTimeout`. On key up clear the timeout and reset it. Once typing has stopped the timeout won't get cleared and will fire — have it fire your request function. It's probably better for a separate question (although I imagine there are already a lot of answers here)

Comment: Thanks, any working example to show the result based on filtering the api response?

Comment: @UI_Dev, I'm actually not sure what you are trying to do. I see the request to the GitHub api, but what is `filter`? Are you trying to filter repos by repo name? Owner name?

Comment: I need to filter by owner name with the github url of the repo as shown in the image

Comment: Okay, but where does `filter` come from. Also you are setting the value  of `searchValue` once, but you don't update it on keyup, so it's always undefined.

Comment: I'm trying to do the filter logic in javascript, but cannot able to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to retrieve the value from the input after it's been typed in. Right now you're just getting the undefined value.

Once you have that, you need to parse the response from GitHub into an object, look for the parts of the response you are interested in, and compare to your filter.

Here we compare the search term to the repo name and the owner login. I've also added some rudimentary debounce code, you might be able to come up with something more robust with some work. There's no error checking here, which you'll probably want, and I'm just dumping the output into a div — you'll probably want to style that.

Hopefully that will give you enough to get started.

```js
var debounceInterval
var debounceWaitTime = 200 // ms
// simple debounce
function UserAction() {
  clearInterval(debounceInterval)
  debounceInterval = setTimeout(sendRequest, debounceWaitTime)
}

function sendRequest() {
  let out = document.getElementById('output')
  out.innerHTML = ''
  // you need to get this value here, not just once at the beginning
  var searchValue = document.getElementById("search").value;

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      let resObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      //Show the name based on filter
      resObj.items.forEach(item => {
        // look in full_name and owner.login for searchValue
        if (item.full_name.toUpperCase().includes(searchValue.toUpperCase()) 
           || item.owner.login.toUpperCase().includes(searchValue.toUpperCase())) {

          out.innerHTML += "Repo: " + item.full_name + ' Owner: ' + item.owner.login + '<br>'

        }
      })
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" + searchValue, true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhttp.send("Your JSON Data Here");
}
```

```html
Search Repo..<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for names.." onkeyup="UserAction()" />
<hr />
 <div id="output">
```

Comment: Thanks Mark :) Appreciate your help